# Pagination clear data after using defaultValue in searchoptions

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqGrid v 4.8.0

[image]

I am facing strange bug: after editing data, when I change page in pager, there is no results:

[image]

I typed

```
$(table_id).jqGrid('GetGridParam','data')
```

And the result is fine (677 records).

After a while of debugging I located the problem. It was in column model. If I use `defaultValue` parameter in `searchoptions`, then the bug appears. When I get rid of this option, there is no problem.

```
{ name: 'TypeId', edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select', editable: true, editoptions: { value: {'1':'1111','2':'2222'} }, search: true, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { defaultValue: '',  value: { '123': '123', '':'gg'} } }
```

But I need this parameter, table doesn't look good if there is some option in filter selected on the beginning. How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Please don't use retro versions. The last released version of free jqGrid is 4.14.1. I'd recommend you to upgrade it first of all. If the problem exist, please provide JSFiddle demo, which reproduces the problem. Additionally you use very strange properties in `searchoptions`. The parameter `searchoptions.value`  has not the same values as `editoptions.value`. Why should the user be able to search for values, which not exist in the grid?

Comment: @Oleg upgrading software isn't something you do while working on big project just because you can. Different searchoptions than editoptions really aren't an issue here

Comment: First of all you should modify 2 lines of your HTML code to load free jqGrid 4.14.1 from CDN to verify whether you have some problem existing only in your retro version of free jqGrid or there are some common problem. The most open source or free software products have simple rule one should update to the last version if it exist. Google Chrome for example publish new version every 1-2 months. Only *the latest version* will be supported. Thus one have to organize the processes so that you can quickly update to the last version.

Comment: @Oleg I understand what you say. Do you try to understand me? Any software upgrade is risky and in my experience always produces tons of issues. Upgrading software requires retesting whole application. Is there any way you can help me, considering that perfect scenarios sometimes don't work in real world?

Comment: Do you tested that the same problem exist in the last version of free jqGrid? If the problem exist, please provide the demo (in jsfiddle, for example), which can be used to reproduce the problem.